# I "have had/have" the book already - what are the differences?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

A: "Do you need this book."

B: "I **have had/have** the book already."

**Example 2**

A: "Do you want to go out this upcoming Sunday?"

B: "Sorry, I **have had/have** another plan for this upcoming Sunday."

What are the differences?

Comment: Do you understand the normal differences between past and present? Did you hear someone use the past tense in that context?

Comment: Use Present Perfect *I **have read** the book* *...so I don't need this (**your**) copy,* OR *...so you can have this (**my**) copy.* But if you just want to turn down the offer because you've already got a copy, use Present Tense *I **have** a copy already.*

Answer (score -1):

In Example 1, "have had" indicates that B obtained the book in the past and still possesses it in the present. It emphasizes the temporal aspect of the action. On the other hand, using "have" simply states the present possession of the book without specifying when it was obtained.

In Example 2, "have had" implies that B made plans for the upcoming Sunday in the past, and those plans are still in effect. It highlights the fact that the plans were made earlier. On the other hand, using "have" indicates that B currently has other plans for the upcoming Sunday, without indicating when those plans were made.

Comment: "Have had" indicates they no longer own the book, but used to, not that they still have it

Comment: "I have had the book already" could be used if you borrowed it from the library last week, read it and returned it a few days later.  "I have had a plan for Sunday" sounds unnatural unless you include a timescale - "I've had a plan for months to go to X on Sunday."

Comment: What @MichaelMortensen said. ***I have had chickenpox*** certainly doesn't mean I caught chickenpox in the past *and am still infected*.

Comment: @Michael Mortensen  So even if "I have had this book already" has "already" in it, it still means it was something I used to have but no longer have now?

Comment: Yes. If you still have the book you would say _I already have it_.